# javascript undefined nodelist returns true

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sets of divs. Fist set is assigned classname `tD`, while the other has a class `tU`. `tD`/`tU` could be undefined. In cases where `tU` is undefined, `tD !== null` returns true in chrome. It actually returns []. Why is this happening?

```
var tD = document.getElementsByClassName("t-d"); // undefined
var tDLength = tD.length;
var tU = document.getElementsByClassName("tU"); //defined
var tULength = tU.length;

while (tU !== null && triangle_up_length > 0) {
        tU[tULength - 1].style.borderLeftWidth = 128 + "px";
        tU[tULength - 1].style.borderRightWidth = 128 + "px";
        tULength--;
}
while (tD !== null && triangle_down_length > 0) {
    tD[tDLength - 1].style.borderLeftWidth = 128 + "px";
    tD[tDLength - 1].style.borderRightWidth = 128 + "px";
    tULength--;
}
```

Comment: then how am i supposed to check the nodelist's existence?

Comment: You should replace `tU !== null` by simply `tU`

Comment: By the way, you should refactor your code to avoid duplicates ;)

Comment: @Mik378where do u think there's a duplicate code?

Comment: Both `while` are very very similar. They just differ by `tU/tD` and `triangle_up_length`/`triangle_down_length`. You can (should) emerge a generic function.  You can drop those variables: `var tDLength`/`var tULength`. Temporary variables in this case are useless and ugly. You can even drop ALL your temporary variables in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (tU.length > 0)` will do what you want.

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an empty nodelist (almost array), if nothing is found, so you shouldn't check for `null`.

Comment: returns an empty array => So why not just: `while(tU.length > 0)`. It would be largely enough.

Comment: thats why it returned []?

Comment: @user3633561 because read documentation, before posting such questions. Nodelist is an array-like object, which doesn't have methods of array prototype, but has length.

Comment: so, checking length on an empty nodelist doesn't cause an error?

Comment: @Mik378which textbook is ur companion JavaScript for web developers 3rd edition(wrox)?

Answer (score 0):

Compete reedit:

```
if( tU ) {
   if( tU.length > 0 ) {
      //do the stuff
   }
{
```

Comment: `if(tU)` would be enough

Comment: it's better to use `if (tU && tU.length > 0)` in this case

Comment: @user3633561 No need for this double operator in this case: `!!tU`

Comment: user3633561 Read the @dentuzhik's solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behavior of GetElementByClassName

"..Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names..". Then you must check for

```
 if( tD.length != 0 ){}
```